# How do you load blocks of different content in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In Django, if I have a page which let's say consists of the following blocks:

1) main content
2) related content
3) new articles
4) advertising block
5) sitewide tags cloud

Should I prepare all data for these blocks in views and then pass it to template via context? If I go this way, every time I need a block on some page, I need to prepare data for it in views. But what if I want to put a new articles block on every page of the site? This means I need to prepare data for this block in every view and pass it to template, which isn't very DRY.

Another option I see, is to create a templatetag, which queries the database and gets latest articles and you just pust this tag on every template you need, but as I understand, this is against main guidelines, which tell that tags should be used for display purposes only (this is no good to make db queries in templatetags).

Which way for displaying blocks in Django do you use/recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that you shouldn't use template tags for this? On the contrary, this is exactly what you should use them for. [Here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/07/django-tips-write-better-template-tags/) for example is a blog entry from James Bennett, one of the early developers of Django, describing exactly that (note that the syntax in that entry is quite out of date, but the principles are still valid).